# How to retrieve Subcollections using Google Cloud Firestore in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I've written the following code:

```
recipient_col = db.collection('Recipient').stream()
list=[]
for docs in recipient_col:
    doc_letter = recipient_col.doc().collection('Letter').stream()
    for docss in doc_letter:
        print(u'{} => {}'.format(docs.id, docs.to_dict()))
```

And when I launch it, It gives this error:

```
'generator' object has no attribute 'doc'
```

Could you please help me solve it?

Comment: Do you want to do `docs.doc()` inside the loop?

Comment: I think you're looking for `doc_letter = docs.collection('Letter').stream()`

Comment: I want to access the every document of letter in the recipient’s document

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. _Could you please help me solve it?_ What do/don't you understand from that error message, exactly?

Comment: I’m aiming to access every document of letter(subcollection) in each of recipient’s(collection) document and i’m unable do it. This code is not working in python what shall I do to access this particular data?